# Database Table erd(2fk from same table)

Tags: database

So i'm making a project. My database looks like this:

Story(many) to (one)user.
Story(one) to (many)review.
Review(one) to (one)user.

There's no distinction between an author/reader. They are just one user. Can read, can submit story.

So i would like to add a like function to my reviews.

So i can print out: "6 others liked this."

At first it wasnt a problem and i could print it. The problem is that, when adding the like button, i ofcourse have to distinguish if the user logged in already liked this review or not.

```
<?php if($liked){?>
<div id="review-like">
<small><?=$row['likes']?> others and you liked this.</small>
<button class="btn btn-success">Liked</button>
</div>
<?php } else{ ?>
<div id="review-like">
<small><?=$row['likes']?> others liked this.</small>
<button class="btn btn-default">Like</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

So in light of that, i have to make another table named "review_liked".

that looks like this:

> review_liked_id(PK),likee_id(user_id|FK[author]),liker_id(user_id|FK[reader]).

My problem is that, idk if the above table is correct or not.

P.S. i googled the word likee and it doesnt exist. I know, but i need something to distinguish the two user_id.

Comment: what do you mean by "table is correct"? if you mean using middle table for many to many relationship, then it is correct.

Comment: I am confused if i am doing it right since my last database lesson was years ago at college. I focus on php. Now im doing a project where im in charge of everything from frontend to backend and the database. 

The ERD looked wierd to me, since its relationship point to the same table?